# IE 11 - Very Weird. PNG only displays after certain page interactions

Tags: javascript, png, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I use JS to create an `Image()` then set the src to be a PNG from a remote location (Amazon S3). When the image has loaded I attach it to the DOM with `appendChild()`.
This works fine in most browsers but in IE11 nothing displays **AT FIRST**.

If I open the dev tools then the image element is there in the DOM but not visible in the actual display. As soon as I toggle a style (any style) off and on in dev tools it appears though.

It also appears if I resize the page (I'm not listening for resize anywhere) or select some text elsewhere in the build. If I click and drag on the area where it *should* be displaying then I get the ghost preview of the image and can drag it around but as soon as I drop it it disappears again.

Most weirdly, if I scroll the page so that part of the area where the image *should* be moves off screen then when I scroll back that part of the image is visible but the rest is still not rendered, as though it has been masked.

I've loaded this same PNG in the past and never seen this issue and I can't see that I'm doing anything different this time round.

Any thoughts? Or do I need to write another email to my boss asking why we even still support that manky old POS.

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal sample to reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue so that we can have a test? Can you load other images correctly using the same way or can you load the image from local using the same functions? Besides, you could also try to add `display: block` style after you append the image into DOM to see if it can solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

IE has planting of issues displaying PNGs, perhaps this might help https://perishablepress.com/css-hackz-series-png-fix-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: Wow! A (relatively) new article that actually talks about supporting IE5.5?? I'll read it but I won't enjoy it :)